# Django, Nginx & Gunicorn - Download reset for large files

Tags: django, nginx, download, timeout, gunicorn

We are working on a Django website alongside with NginX and Gunicorn.
We have to provide the possibility to download large tar.gz files (up to 30Go) which are permanently stored whithin the tree structure.

Oddly, when we download one of these archives (~9Go) we get the 1-2 first Go, then the download resets and reinitialize from 0.

The logs showed that the worker was timeout.

I tried to serve the files in chunk sizes with Django : no change.

I tried to set *_timeout values in Nginx conf file: no change.

The only way to have the download going to its end was to set an unlimited timeout (timeout 0) in gunicorn.service file.

I don't understand very well why do I need to set this unlimited timeout on Gunicorn ... I though that NginX would be able to manage the file download.

May you please enlight me about the reasons of this ?

What are we doing wrong ?

Thank you very much for your help

**gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=dev
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/web
ExecStart=/web/env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 4 \
          --timeout 0 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/website**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name myservername;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        server_name mysername;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/myservername_cert.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/myservername.key;

        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_send_timeout 300;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                access_log off; log_not_found off;
        }

        location /static/ {
                root /web/frontend;
        }

        location /data/ {
                try_files $uri = 404;
                sendfile on;
                tcp_nopush on;
                tcp_nodelay on;
                root /web/frontend;
        }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
}
```

**Django download function**

```
def full_data_download(request, field_name):
    
    the_file = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) +field_name+'_FULL.tar.gz'
    filename = os.path.basename(the_file)
    chunk_size = 8192
    response = FileResponse(FileWrapper(open(the_file, 'rb'), chunk_size),
                            content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(the_file)[0])
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(the_file)    
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}'.format(filename)
    return response
```